# Mantain user defined meta data with customised functions for tm_map

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I have a function which I use to translate tokens based on a key/value dictionary.

```
dictionary <- c("casa", "barco", "carro", "arbol")
names(dictionary) <- c("home", "boat", "car", "tree")

translate2 <- function (text, dictionary) {
  text_out <- character(0)
  for (i in 1:length(text)) {
    text.split <- strsplit(text[i], "\\s")
    translation <- dictionary[unlist(text.split)]
    text_out <- append(text_out, paste(translation, sep="", collapse=" "))
  }
  PlainTextDocument(text_out, id = ID(text), author = Author(text))
}
```

This function works correctly for the meta `Author:

```
library(tm)

text <- "My car is on the tree next to my home under the boat"
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
meta(corpus, "Author", type="local") <- "Kant"
meta(corpus, "TextID", type="local") <- "121212"
meta(corpus[[1]], "Author")
# [1] "Kant"

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, translate2, dictionary)
meta(corpus[[1]], "Author")
# [1] "Kant" 
corpus[[1]]
# NA carro NA NA NA arbol NA NA NA casa NA NA barco
```

But when I try to pass a user-defined meta like `TextID` with the slightly modified version of the function

```
translate1 <- function (text, dictionary) {
  text_out <- character(0)
  for (i in 1:length(text)) {
    text.split <- strsplit(text[i], "\\s")
    translation <- dictionary[unlist(text.split)]
    text_out <- append(text_out, paste(translation, sep="", collapse=" "))
  }
  PlainTextDocument(text_out, id = ID(text), author = Author(text), 
                    TextID = TextID(text))
}
```

I get

```
text <- "My car is on the tree next to my home under the boat"
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
meta(corpus, "Author", type="local") <- "Kant"
meta(corpus, "TextID", type="local") <- "121212"
meta(corpus[[1]], "Author")
# [1] "Kant"
meta(corpus[[1]], "TextID")
# [1] "121212"

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, translate1, dictionary)
# Error in PlainTextDocument(text_out, id = ID(text), author = Author(text),  : 
#                              unused argument (TextID = TextID(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your approach:

1. `PlainTextDocument` has no argument `TextID` (this caused your error)
2. There is no function named `TextID`

From `?PlainTextDocument`, it seems that the argument you're looking for is called `localmetadata`.

Here's a version of `translate1` that seems to work as expected:

```
translate1 <- function (text, dictionary) {
  text_out <- character(0)
  for (i in 1:length(text)) {
    text.split <- strsplit(text[i], "\\s")
    translation <- dictionary[unlist(text.split)]
    text_out <- append(text_out, paste(translation, sep="", collapse=" "))
  }
  PlainTextDocument(text_out, id = ID(text), author = Author(text), 
                    localmetadata = list(TextID = meta(text, "TextID")))
} 

text <- "My car is on the tree next to my home under the boat"
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
meta(corpus, "Author", type="local") <- "Kant"
meta(corpus, "TextID", type="local") <- "121212"
meta(corpus[[1]], "Author")
# [1] "Kant"
meta(corpus[[1]], "TextID")
# [1] "121212"

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, translate1, dictionary)
meta(corpus[[1]], "Author")
# [1] "Kant"
meta(corpus[[1]], "TextID")
# [1] "121212"
corpus[[1]]
# NA carro NA NA NA arbol NA NA NA casa NA NA barco
```